# Why doesn't my LESS read from the browser?

Tags: joomla, less

I'm working with a Joomla website, is not the first time that I use the LESS CSS, but this time I don't know why this is not working.
I've downloaded the last less.js from the website and I insert this before the end of tag HEAD, I call the CSS
before the js, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/main.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/style.less" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/templateskit.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/js/less-1.5.0.min.js"></script>
```

If I check in the code of my website I see that the path is correct and I can see the code correctly, but the browser don't read the less css and I don't know why!

Comment: Which browser? A specific browser or all of them?

Comment: all of them! Thank your for the time!

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(Solution moved from question to answer)</sub>

> There was a `box-shadow` property present in my LESS file; that was what gave me this problem! Removing it fixed it.